# iOS 8 - Keyboard Jumps when using Autocorrect

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

My view has two `UITextFields`. Let's call them TF1 and TF2. TF1 has autocorrectionType equal to UITextAutocorrectionTypeYes; TF2 has autocorrectionType equal to UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo. When going from TF1 to TF2, the transition is seamless. The predictive autocorrect toolbar disappears when going to TF2 and all is good.

The problem comes in when going from TF2 to TF1. When the autocorrect toolbar needs to be displayed, the whole keyboard will jump to the toolbar position then move itself down. It creates a jerky animation. What is causing this animation and how can I code for it? I would like these two textfields to have different autocorrection types, but still keep the transitions between them smooth.

Answer (score 0):

I had a case something like your question in my app. What I did is just before entering the textview  or textfield with UITextAutocorrectionTypeYes to disable the animations in UIView with [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];

You can do something like this:

> - (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView  {
>     [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO]; 
>     return YES; }
> - (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView  { 
>     [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];  }

It not the most beautiful solution, but maybe it can help you to solve it:)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me. I used these delegate methods to go between my textfields and the keyboard still jumps.